# fork() outputs after the process execution is over

Tags: c, fork

Consider the below code snippet:

```
int main()
{
    fork();
    fork();
    fork();
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

I am getting the output:[ubuntu 12.04]

```
aashish@aashish-laptop:~$ ./a.out
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
aashish@aashish-laptop:~$ Hello World <---------------------------
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

Why "Hello Word" is outputted after the process execution is over?

Comment: Probably because when that process exits, there's another process running from the fork that is still outputting.

Comment: So many dupes of this question on SO... everyday...

Comment: Strictly, `fork()` doesn't output anything, of course. The various processes created by `fork()` output a line before exiting. Sometimes, the top-level process (the initial process) completes before some of its children, so the children write their output after the shell has written its prompt for the next command. If you want the parent to wait (`waitpid()` or `wait()`) until its children have died before exiting, you have to code that. You could/should include the PID (`getpid()`) in the printed information; it would help you see what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that you are creating multiple processes, which run asynchronously with respect to each other. The long answer follows:

When you type *./a.out* at the shell prompt, that creates a process running your program. Let's call that process 1.

Process 1 calls fork(). This creates a new child process, Process 2, and both 1 and 2 carry on execution after the first fork() call, proceeding to the second fork() call. Process 1 creates child Process 3, and Process 2 creates child process 4. All four processes carry on from after the second fork(), proceeding to the final fork() call. Process 1 creates Process 5; Process 2 creates Process 6; Process 3 creates Process 7; and Process 4 creates Process 8.

[image: non-artist's rendering of process hierarchy]

Note that these process numbers are arbitrary: there's no guarantee they'd be created in that order.

The asynchrony comes into play as soon as that first fork() gets executed. The system offers no guarantees about scheduling the parent with respect to the child. Theoretically the child could run to completion before the parent continues, the parent could finish before the child gets any resources. The most likely scenario lies somewhere in the middle: the original process shares resources with its progeny, so that all run concurrently.

The final piece of the puzzle results from the fact that the shell is waiting for Process 1 to complete. *Only* Process 1. The shell doesn't know (or care) that Process 1 has started other processes. So when Process 1 completes, the shell displays a prompt. As it happened, some of the descendants of Process 1 hadn't yet reached the printf() statement. By the time they got there, the shell had already displayed its prompt.

To explore this further, you might want to try changing the *fork()* calls to *printf( "%d\n", fork() );* and/or change *printf("Hello World\n")* to *printf("Hello from pid %d\n", getpid() )*

Answer (score 3):

The "Hello World" outputs that come after the second shell prompt come from the forked processes, not from the one that was launched by the shell (you).

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you make 1 fork (2), then you fork again (4), then again (8) then for each fork print Hello world. That's why you got 8 outputs.

Comment: Your answer is accurate as far as it goes, but it doesn't explain why some of the output appears after the initial process has exited and the shell has written its next prompt.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
    pid_t c[3];
    int i, n = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        switch ((c[n] = fork())) {
        case 0:  break;
        case -1: perror("fork"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        default: ++n;
        }
    }
    printf("[%d] Hello World\n", (int)getpid());
    // Without waiting, some children may still be running when the
    // parent exits. This makes it look like output is generated
    // after the process is over, when in fact not all the processes
    // are done yet.
    //
    // The process is not really finished until its children are
    // finished. The wait call waits on a child process to finish.
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) wait(0);
    return 0;
}
```